# SSL authentication with certification for python 2.6.6

Tags: python, http, ssl

I have some python code to make a https post request (api call) and under python3, and need to convert it to python 2.6.6

I was searching online for some solutions but still unclear of what is the equivalent SSL functions in 2.6.6 from what I currently have.

```
import ssl
import http.client

   context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile='mycer.cer')
   context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
   context.load_cert_chain(certfile='mycrt.crt', keyfile='mykey.key', 
   password='mypass')

   conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("example.com", context=context)
```

So this above snippet allows me to connect to the webpage with SSL cert authentication and then I can proceed to make my get/post requests.

I know http.client is known as httplib in python 2.x, however the SSL functions i use need at least 2.7.9 python and 2.6.6 doesn't have the create_default_context function.

Any ideas how to create the equivalent in python2.6.6?

Thanks guys for your help

Comment: I recommend to not invest time into implementing it with this ancient Python version (released 2010) but that you move instead to a recent Python version. Even if you solve this problem you get likely more problems since this old version likely comes with an ancient OpenSSL where you get lots of trouble to connect to recent SSL servers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'd want to do this as well using the newer versions, but for work purposes, upgrading is not an option.

Comment: You'll find the documentation for SSL support in python 2.6 [here](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/ssl.html). As far as I'm aware python 2.6 did not check any certificates by default. Also I think it did not support SNI which can also often causes the SSL handshake to fail. You can also use directly [httplib.HTTPConnection](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection). This also does no certificate validation.